# Sending SMS and Email in Windows 8 programmatically

Tags: windows-8

I would like to send SMS and Email via my C# code. How can I do that. In Wp7 we have SMScomposetask and Emailcomposetask. Whats the equivalent of that in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/windows8-metro-app-winrt-send-email-emailcomposetask.aspx):

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=recipient@example.com&subject=The subject of an email&body=Hello from a Windows 8 Metro app."); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

There is an example of how to send an SMS message [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sms-SendReceive-fa02e55e).  It uses the `SendSmsMessageOperation` class. However:

> Note  This functionality is only available to mobile operator apps and
>   Windows Store apps given privileged access by mobile network
>   operators, mobile broadband adapter IHV, or OEM. For more information,
>   see Mobile Broadband: Windows Store device apps.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh852368.aspx).

Comment: See my edit.  Basically you use the `SendSmsMessageOperation` but it has limited availability.